# is it possible to change the size of audio player in html5

Tags: html, html5-audio

Is there any possibility of changing the size if the audio player in html5 produced using audio tag.

Comment: Yes, there are _lots_ of ways of customizing audio players. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I am trying to keep the code simple. i have just insert the audio tag until now.I just want to increase the width of the player.I want to avoid use of any libraries.

Comment: You can also consider `zoom: 70%;`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`<audio>` can be styled as any other html element.

To increase the width just use the css property `width`.

Some html:

```
<audio id="player" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://xseignard.github.com/webGLWebAudioAPI/sound/OGLikeCapone.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>​​​
```

And the css:

```
#player {
 width: 100%;
}​
```

Regards